# Worklight 6.2: Is JSONStore supported for windows8 platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

We have developed a hybrid mobile app using IBM Worklight 6.2.0.1. We are using JSONStore to store user credential on Andoird and iOS devices. I would like to know, if worklight 6.2 has support for JSONStore on windows8 platform ?

As per worklight 6.2 document - https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html?lang=en

The table shows, JSONStore is supported for Windows8 and Windows8 Phone but the document says - The JSONStore feature is only available on iOS and Android devices and simulators.

So it is not clear, if JSONStore is supported for Windows8 platform or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an omission in the text.

The JSONStore feature is supported in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.
We'll have the text corrected.